# Convert an R script that saves CSV files and creates plots to a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, rscript

I have a script in R that used a lot of packages. In the script, first it asks for input file (the input is not common but with one package it is readable), and then do something to the input at background (need for process of the code), and then ask for a number that also needs for coming line and plot result here then used "write.csv" to save some CSV in the directory and ask to complete them and again ask to upload them and continued the code (the CSVs has really long list).
At the end the results will display as some plots.
I used "svDialogs" and "tcltk" packages for pop-up menu to browse input and give some messages (with OK button).

Everything works fine in the script, but all I'm asking is how to create a shiny app of this script?
If it's possible give me some tips about how to write the code in ui.R and server.R, I can handle the others. (For example how to appear download csv and input AFTER the start of shiny with continue button or something like this. I don't want all the menus and inputs shows at the start of shiny).

I'm not sure that even if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Shiny app, take a look at: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html

Regarding your question 'how to appear download csv and input AFTER the start of shiny', check [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) package. There are some functions there to do exactly what you want to do: show() and hide()